# Plotting variable horizontal lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with multiple data frames that look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016),
             number = c(100, 120, 125, 140),
             capacity = c(125, 125, 150, 150))
```

I want to plot `number` as bars by `year` and with reference to `capacity`. More specifically, I want to show whether and to what extent the value for `number` exceeds that of `capacity`, wherein the latter is plotted as a horizontal line.

When `capacity` does not change over time, I can easily achieve this by doing `ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = number)) + geom_col() + geom_hline(yintercept = capacity)`. However, when I do this with data frames such as the one above, I logically get multiple lines that span the entire range of the plot.

I tried multiple possible solutions to this problem. A series of calls to `geom_segment` is not practical, since I am working with many data frames and `capacity` varies idiosyncratically. A second solution was:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = number)) + 
       geom_col(width= 0.75) +
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = capacity, ymax = capacity), color = "red", size = 2)
```

This gives me horizontal bars in all the right places, but they are not connected horizontally and - more importantly - vertically.

Finally, the lines are connected when calling `geom_step` like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = number)) + 
       geom_col(width= 0.75) +
       geom_step(aes(y = capacity, x = year), color = "red", size = 2)
```

However, the problem here is that the step function does not change when I want it to (i.e. in between years so that it becomes clear when `capacity` has changed). This can be remedied by shifting the aesthetics in `geom_step` to `aes(y = capacity, x = year-0.5)`, but then the line does not extend far enough on the right side of the plot.

Hope it is halfway clear what I am trying to accomplish. Ideally, by the way, I would like to extend the reference line to the edges of the plot, as is the case when calling `geom_hline()`.

Comment: Another option entirely would be to simply `tidyr::gather()` the data frame and then plot bars for both number and capacity, dodged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for your more general case? This just uses the adjustment on the
`geom_step` aesthetic in combination with programmatically adding an extra row to fill in the last point in the red line. The last point is one more than the largest year in the data, combined with the last capacity value. Note that your original data is not changed.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(year = c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016),
                 number = c(100, 120, 125, 140),
                 capacity = c(125, 125, 150, 150))

ggplot(
  data = df %>% 
    arrange(year) %>% 
    add_row(year = max(.$year) + 1, capacity = last(.$capacity)),
  mapping = aes(x = year, y = number)
) + 
  geom_col(width= 0.75) +
  geom_step(aes(y = capacity, x = year - 0.5), color = "red", size = 2)
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Cheers, that does it, basically. Since I wanted the red line to extend to the edges of the plot, I added another one row on the left and two rows on the right and then zoomed in using `coord_cartesian()`. It is hacky and I'd rather not change the data, but it works.